# Angular 8 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, angular, build, callstack, rollup

I am getting below errors when trying to build the Angular project on Jenkins, but this issue is not happening on my local.
Hence I couldn't reproduce the issue and figure out the cause.
Highly appreciate it if anyone has any ideas or experiences on that could give me some advice.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
 at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
 at Module.removeExistingSourceMap (/xxxxxx/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:13859:56)
 at Module.setSource (/xxxxxx/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:13640:14)
 at Promise.resolve.catch.then.then.then  (/xxxxxx/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:16423:20)
```

Comment: I had the same error, it was due to a circular dependency

Comment: @Nizar Khsib Thanks for your comment! Would you mind sharing with me what kinds of circular dependency you had or any examples?